# Dot appears before line with round linecap FF,IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to do a simple line drawing animation using SVG.
I am using javascript to find the length of the path and then set the `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-dasharray` as the shapes are dynamic.
A simple demo is shown below

```js
var path = document.querySelector("path");
path.style.strokeDasharray = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.strokeDashoffset = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.strokeLinecap = "round";
setTimeout(function(){
 path.style.transition = "stroke-dashoffset 1s"
 path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
},1000)
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <path d="m10,10 h100 v100 h-100 v-100" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

The above snippet works perfectly in Chrome. But in Firefox and Edge a dot appears before the line is animated. It appears only if `stroke-linecap=round` is specified. Otherwise it works as intended. [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/74u6mLhg/1/)

Firefox:

[image]

Any ideas on how to remove the dot ?

Comment: How about moving `path.style.strokeLinecap = "square";` to `setTimeout`? https://jsfiddle.net/dvq58seL/1/

Comment: Someone should raise a Chrome bug. "Works perfectly" is not a very accurate description of what Chrome is doing here.

Comment: Wait so other browsers are rendering like it should and Chrome is doing it wrong ? @RobertLongson

Comment: @akshay That's what I think FWIW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's arguably a bug, but it occurs because your dash offset starts exactly where the dash ends. So the browser considers that there is a zero-length dash before the gap starts.  Round caps are added to the end of a line - even if it has zero length.

```
dash-array = 20 20
####################                    ####################
                   ^
                   dashoffset = 20
```

One easy way to work around this is to make the dash pattern have a gap that's wider than the solid part. Then start the animation within the gap, instead of right at the start of it.

```
dash-array = 20 21
####################                     ####################
                    ^
                    dashoffset = 20.5
```

And the dot goes away.

```js
var path = document.querySelector("path");
path.style.strokeDasharray = [path.getTotalLength(), path.getTotalLength() + 1].join(' ');
path.style.strokeDashoffset = path.getTotalLength() + 0.5;
path.style.strokeLinecap = "round";
setTimeout(function(){
 path.style.transition = "stroke-dashoffset 1s"
 path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
},1000)
```

```css
path {
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <path d="m10,10 h100 v100 h-100 v-100" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this killer way:
Give css into your svg path: like `path{stroke-opacity: 0;}` and add `path.style.strokeOpacity = "1";` into your Timeout function. *please see above code*

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarifications.

```js
  
  var path = document.querySelector("path");
path.style.strokeDasharray = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.strokeDashoffset = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.strokeLinecap = "round";
setTimeout(function(){
  path.style.transition = "stroke-dashoffset 1s"
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
  path.style.strokeOpacity = "1";
},2000)
```

```css
path{stroke-opacity: 0;}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <path d="m10,10 h100 v100 h-100 v-100" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked too. However i am going with @Paul's answer because i have too many paths and adjusting the stroke dasharray would be easier.